# WLSTException: Error occured while performing connect : Error getting the initial context. There is no server running

Tags: weblogic

Hii I am facing issue while connecting to weblogic server. The command i used to connect to it is as follows:

```
java -Dweblogic.security.SSL.ignoreHostnameVerification=true -
Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -DUseSunHttpHandler=true -
Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.awt.headless=true -
Dsun.jnu.encoding=ISO-8859-1 -Dfile.encoding=ISO-8859-1 weblogic.WLST 
<path>/weblogic_configuration_domain_update.py <path>/weblogic-
domain.properties
```

It gives following error:

```
javax.naming.CommunicationException [Root exception is 
java.net.ConnectException: t3://<IP>:<port>: Destination 
unreachable; nested exception is: java.net.ConnectException: Connection 
refused; No available router to destination]
Problem invoking WLST - Traceback (innermost last):
File "/<path>/weblogic_configuration_domain_update.py", line 134, in ?
File "<iostream>", line 22, in connect
File "<iostream>", line 648, in raiseWLSTException
WLSTException: Error occured while performing connect : Error getting the 
initial context. There is no server running at t3://<IP>:<port>
```

Please let me know is there any way to resolve this issue. Thank you in advance.

Comment: could you share your phyton code? the error says the weblogic managed instance is not running. Are you sure the admin console is up and running?

Answer (score 0):

you have to insert the correct values in the script: weblogic_configuration_domain_update.py

for example: `connect(t3://thelisteingadressofthehost.network.com:thelisteningportoftheAdminServer)`

and be sure which protocol you are using `t3` or `t3s`...

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs92/config_scripting/reference.html

Comment: @Suneha   Are you able to resolve this issue?  I am getting the same error and no luck yet.

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal and add mentioned below variable `JVM_ARGS`

```sh
[oracle@node1 bin]$ set JVM_ARGS="-Dprod.props.file='${WL_HOME}'/.product.properties ${WLST_PROPERTIES} ${JVM_D64} ${UTILS_MEM_ARGS} ${COMMON_JVM_ARGS} ${CONFIG_JVM_ARGS} -Dweblogic.security.TrustKeyStore=DemoTrust"

[oracle@node1 bin]$ wlst.sh

Initializing WebLogic Scripting Tool (WLST) ...
Welcome to WebLogic Server Administration Scripting Shell
Type help() for help on available commands
wls:/offline>
```